# Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutterbluetooth">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <application
        android:label="flutterbluetooth"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            ...
        </activity>
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am trying to get bluetooth permission in flutter. But I am getting the error in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to declare these additional permissions which are newly added, along with legacy bluettoth permission.
You can choose only specific permission based on your requirement.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions).